# GetPrivateProfileString not working .NET

Tags: c#, kernel32

I want to make an INI reader with `GetPrivateProfileString`. What I'm using:

```
public class Config
{
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Default, StringBuilder RetVal, int Size, string FilePath);

    private string path;

    public Config(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public string PopValue(string section, string key)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", sb, sb.Length, path);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now my INI file:

```
[mysql]
host=localhost
```

And what I use:

```
Console.WriteLine(Configuration.PopValue("mysql", "host"));
```

However, it just prints out a blank line instead of `localhost`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Never** use GetPrivateProfileString(), it is horribly expensive due to its appcompat behavior.  Reading a *single* ini parameter costs 50 msec.  Read 20 of them and you've blown your startup time.  The format is simple, easy enough to parse yourself with StreamReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use third party library try using [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net).
I use it and is very easy to create/manage complex INI files and is opensource.

`GetPrivateProfileString` Signature is

```
DWORD WINAPI GetPrivateProfileString(
  _In_   LPCTSTR lpAppName,
  _In_   LPCTSTR lpKeyName,
  _In_   LPCTSTR lpDefault,
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpReturnedString,
  _In_   DWORD nSize,
  _In_   LPCTSTR lpFileName
);
```

So out is not `StringBuilder` use `String`

Comment: Nini works fine, I guess I'll just use Nini, it's much easier :) Thanks.

Comment: You can _also_ use a `StringBuilder` as `out` parameter

Answer (score 7):

YES, You CAN use a StringBuilder if you like and here is the solution:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Default, StringBuilder RetVal, int Size, string FilePath);

public string PopValue(string section, string key)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
    int n = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", sb, 4096, path);
    if(n<1) return string.Empty;
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The problem is that you passed in a zero length when you passed sb.Length and it was interpreted by the imported function that there was NO SPACE in which to write the return value - so it wrote nothing.

Comment: Where is `path` defined? The one listed as the last argument to `GetPrivateProfileString()`?

Comment: `path` is the full path to the filename e.g. "C:\Tmp\MySettings.ini"